# Build Job from Jenkins Pipeline with variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not able to build a job from jenkins pipeline passing a variable for job name. Please find below the code snippet. If I replace ${service} with 'microservice' it will trigger the job

```
service = 'microservice'
echo "TESSSSSSSSTTT ${service}"
build(job: "'${service}'", parameters: [string(name: 'ENVNAME', value: 'uat')])
```

The error faced is:

```
[Pipeline] echo
TESSSSSSSSTTT microservice
[Pipeline] build
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: No item named 'microservice' found
Finished: FAILURE
```

I'm using this method because I want to hit a build command for all the microservices passing the names with multi-line string parameter, finally I want to set this build into a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your job is not called `'microservice'` in Jenkins but `microservice` (without the ticks).

So change your `build` line to not include single quotes after the double quote:

```
build(job: "${service}", parameters: [string(name: 'ENVNAME', value: 'uat')])
```

Did some simple test with my jenkins instance and was able to call a job by setting the service variable to an existing job name.

Comment: Thanks, works I think i test this with double quotation only inside the loop and failed with ERR: Please check groups! java.util.AbstractList$Itr . I see outside the loop works perfect. Thanks again.